# Python Tkinter label not destroying

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm attempting to make a program with tkinter, and so far, things have gone somewhat as hoped, and I nearly achieved what I wanted.
But I've got a problem with destroying labels.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def controleerAntwoord(gekozenHeld, submit, eersteHintButton):
    antwoord = entry.get()
    if antwoord == gekozenHeld:
        submit.destroy()
        eersteHintButton.destroy()
        eersteHint("destroy", button)
        startspel()


def eersteHint(superheldHint, button):
    hintTextLabel = Label(root, text = "First hint: ")
    hintLabel = Label(root, text = superheldHint)
    if superheldHint != "destroy":
        hintTextLabel.pack()
        hintLabel.pack()
        button.destroy()
    if superheldHint == "destroy":
        hintTextLabel.destroy()
        hintLabel.destroy()

def startspel():
    entry.delete(0, 'end')
    gekozenHeld = "test"
    superheldHint1 = 'hey'
    eersteHintButton = Button(root, text = "Give First Hint", command = lambda: eersteHint(superheldHint1, eersteHintButton))
    submit = Button(root, text = "Submit Answer",foreground = "blue",     command = lambda: controleerAntwoord(gekozenHeld, submit, eersteHintButton))
    eersteHintButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    entry.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    submit.pack(side = BOTTOM, pady = 20)



def start_up():
    name = entry.get().strip()
    if name != "":
        button.destroy()
        giveName.destroy()
        startspel()


giveName = Label(root, text="Insert your name: ")
entry = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=start_up)
entry.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is my current code so far, I know it looks big, but a lot of it can be ignored for this question.

As to how the program works, you enter your name and get taken to the next window.
There you can press the submit button and enter some text, as well as asking for a hint.

When you press the hint button, you get some text on the screen, and when you submit the correct answer, which in this case, is "test", the text should disappear. But it does not.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The indentation of the code in your question needs fixing. Also, there's nowhere where you call destroy. Why do you think this should destroy a  label?

Comment: I indeed forgot to replace .forget() with .destroy, I edited that. And what do you mean with indentation?

Comment: The word `def` has the same indentation as the next line. The body of a function needs to have an extra level of indentation from the `def` line.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I fixed it. But do you also happen to know why hintTextLabel.destroy() and hintLabel.destroy() aren't doing anything? I've completely run out of ideas.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. If I pass in "destroy", then it destroys the just-created label, and the button appears. If I don't pass in "destroy", then it leaves the label but destroys the button.

Comment: That's weird, because in my whole code, it doesn't function properly. Should I perhaps upload everything?

Comment: Not everything, just a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see how the edited code you posted can possibly work. The start button depends on data that you entered, but the entry widget isn't visible to enter anything.  Please take the time to post a proper [mcve] that actually works and reproduces the problem.

Comment: I've edited the original post, now it should include the minimal of my program, whilst still showing what's going wrong. I forgot to put an entry.pack() at the bottom.

Comment: Are you expecting that the _second_ time `eersteHint` is called that it destroys the widgets from the _first_ time it was called?

Comment: That's indeed the exact thing I'm attempting to do, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to. I just realised what I'm doing wrong, but I wouldn't know how to do it right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a local variable, but expecting that local variable to somehow be remembered the second time you call the function. All your code does is create a label and then immediately destroy *the one it just created*. If you want it to destroy the one created earlier, you'll have to store that in a global variable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now what I did wrong, and how to fix it. I've got to figure out what that means for my whole code, but now I know what I was doing wrong. Thanks for sticking by me! <3